# Issue with multiple javascript slideshows on the same page

Tags: javascript, css, slider, slideshow, autoplay

I'm trying to make multiple slideshows to work with the same piece of javascript code.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="slider-container">
    
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide">...</div>
        <div class="slide">...</div>
        <div class="slide">...</div>
        <div class="slide">...</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide">...</div>
        <div class="slide">...</div>
        <div class="slide">...</div>
        <div class="slide">...</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is the main CSS:

```
.slider-container{
    width:50%;
}
        
.slider{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:75%; /* aspect-ratio 4/3 */
}
        
.slide{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in;
}
        
.slide:first-child{
    opacity:1;
}
```

and here is the javascript :

```
const sliderContainer = document.querySelector(".slider-container");
const slide = sliderContainer.querySelectorAll(".slide");
let currentSlide = 0;
        
function changeSlide() {
    slide[currentSlide].style.opacity = 0;
    currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % slide.length;
    slide[currentSlide].style.opacity = 1;
}
        
function startSlider() {
    intervalId = setInterval(changeSlide, 2000);
}
        
function stopSlider() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
}
        
startSlider();
sliderContainer.addEventListener("mouseenter", stopSlider);
sliderContainer.addEventListener("mouseleave", startSlider);
```

This javascript works well for one slideshow but II can't get more than one to work on the same page. Ideally, I would like to keep the same class for all the slideshows and obviously make the enter/leave mouse events work individualy for each of them. Any help ?

Comment: I assume you need to show all the slideshow in parallel?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to build a portfolio gallery and some of the items are running slideshows.

Comment: Okay, I have added my answer. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To handle multiple sliders on one page with independent behaviors, you need to change your JS code to work with each slider separately.

First way to do this is by encapsulating the functionality for each slider within a function and then creating instances for each slider.

Here is your code:

html:

```
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider" id="slider1">
    <div class="slide">...</div>
    <div class="slide">...</div>
    <div class="slide">...</div>
    <div class="slide">...</div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider" id="slider2">
    <div class="slide">...</div>
    <div class="slide">...</div>
    <div class="slide">...</div>
    <div class="slide">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function createSlider(sliderId) {
  const sliderContainer = document.getElementById(sliderId);
  const slides = sliderContainer.querySelectorAll(".slide");
  let currentSlide = 0;
  let intervalId;

  function changeSlide() {
    slides[currentSlide].style.opacity = 0;
    currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % slides.length;
    slides[currentSlide].style.opacity = 1;
  }

  function startSlider() {
    intervalId = setInterval(changeSlide, 2000);
  }

  function stopSlider() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }

  startSlider();
  sliderContainer.addEventListener("mouseenter", stopSlider);
  sliderContainer.addEventListener("mouseleave", startSlider);
}

// Create instances for each slider
createSlider("slider1");
createSlider("slider2");
```

Changes in the code:

1. The `createSlider` function takes the `sliderId` parameter, who will be used to identify each slider container.
2. Inside the function, I use `document.getElementById` to find the specific slider container based on the provided `sliderId`.
3. The rest of the logic is encapsulated within the function, ensuring that each slider work independently.

So, you can create as many sliders as you need by calling `createSlider` with different `sliderId` values. Each slider will have it own set of event listeners and will function independently of the others.

Comment: Thanks Eliseo, it’s simple and works well, but I’m wondering if there is a solution without having to modify the javascript each time I add a new slideshow to the page. I  tried the forEach method (const sliderContainer = document.querySelectorAll(“.sllider-container”); … sliderContainer.forEach((slide,currentSlide) => …) and I tried also to loop through the slider container (for(var i = 0, i < sliderContainer.length, i++) { const slide = sliderContainer[i].querySelectorAll(“.slide”) …). Without success. I'm actually a designer (not a coder), so I must do something wrong.

Comment: Or, more close to your solution,  create an unique ID for each slider container and apply the function for each ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const sliderContainer = document.querySelector(".slider-container");
const slider = sliderContainer.querySelectorAll(".slider");
let intervals = [];

function startSlider() {
  slider.forEach(everySlider => {
    const slides = everySlider.children;
    let count = 0;
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      if(count === slides.length){
        count = 0;
      }
      for(let i=0; i<slides.length; i++){
        slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
      }
      slides[count].style.opacity = 1;
      count++;
    }, 2000);
    intervals.push(intervalId);
  });
}

function stopSlider(){
  intervals.forEach(interval => clearInterval(interval));
}

startSlider();
sliderContainer.addEventListener("mouseenter", stopSlider);
sliderContainer.addEventListener("mouseleave", startSlider);
```

```css
.slider-container{
    width:50%;
}
        
.slider{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:75%; /* aspect-ratio 4/3 */
}
        
.slide{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in;
}
        
.slide:first-child{
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide">1</div>
        <div class="slide">2</div>
        <div class="slide">3</div>
        <div class="slide">4</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide">5</div>
        <div class="slide">6</div>
        <div class="slide">7</div>
        <div class="slide">8</div>
    </div>
</div>
```